A short story about very small elephants who could fly
I read a very funny short story about 15 or 20 years ago, in a collection.
A few people were discussing, over a few drinks, about genetic manipulations allowing to create versions of existing animals, very larger, or very smaller, than the natural ones.
One of them suggested that elephants, in very very tiny versions, might be able to fly just by flapping their ears, like Dumbo. Another one agreed on the principle, but pointed out that the energy requirements would be very high. Then someone (the first speaker, or a third party, I don't remember) suggested that nutriments with a very concentrated energy content would be needed, for instance strong alcoholic beverages.
This is when they noticed that the glasses containing their drinks were certainly not as full as when they had started this conversation and that there were traces, between the glasses, that evoked very very small elephant feet...

LOL ! Thanks ! I just corrected it. Damn automatic correction...  I'm not sure what I originally typed, but it was probably "yreas". I keep writing letters in the wrong order. I am lysdexic. This is not a typo, it is the real name (based on a pun) of my trouble. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lysdexia

Heh, that etymology is incomplete.  I remember it being a winning entry (or at least an honourable mention) in an Omni contest for humorous malapropisms, which would push it back at least 5 years prior to 1990.

@DavidW Hey ! I did not write this etmyology ! I just quoted Wiknotiary..

Not blaming you, just finding bits of humour in small things...

@DavidW So am i.... ;)

I am aware of a book including tiny green elephants with wings oh so blue who get their energy from cookies.

@stannius Looks interesting. But my story was that one, energy from alcohol !

This is one of the "Gavagan's Bar" stories, "Elephas Frumenti," from Tales from Gavagan's Bar by L. Sprague de Camp and Fletcher Pratt (1950).
Tiny elephants might fly:

"By no means, sir. In the case of size-reduction, it works in your favor. The mass is divided by eight, but the muscles remain proportionately the same, capable of supporting a vastly greater weight. The legs and wings of a tiny elephant would not only support him, but give him the agility of a humming-bird. Consider the dwarf elephants of Sicily during the Plish—"
"Alvin," said Mrs. Jonas, "you're drunk. Otherwise you'd remember how to pronounce Pleistocene, and you wouldn’t be talking about elephants' wings."
"Not at all, my dear. I should confidently expect such a species to develop flight by means of enlarged ears, like the Dumbo of the movies."

And tiny elephants drank the drinks:

The glass that had held his drink was empty. Thott's still held about half a cocktail. Mrs. Jonas' glass lay on its side, and from its lip about a thimbleful of Presidente cocktail had flowed pinkly into an irregular patch the size of a child’s hand.
As the other two followed Witherwax's finger, they saw that from this patch a line of little liquid footprints led across the table to the far edge, where they ceased suddenly. They were circular, each about the size of a dime, with a small scalloped front edge, as if made by...


Elephas rather than Elphas. But it is indeed this story.

@Alfred Oops, fixed.  Thanks.  I was paying so much attention to spelling "Frumenti" correctly I missed the typo.
